# Equation of a tangent to a circle (proof)

Tags: tangent-line

The equation of a tangent line  to a circle ( center at $(x_m, y_m)$ and radius $r$) at the point $(x_0,y_0)$ is given by:

\begin{align}
(x-x_m)(x_0-x_m)+(y-y_m)(y_0-y_m)=r^2.
\end{align}

How to derive this expression?

Comment: Actually, the equation of a circle with center at $(x_m,y_m)$ and radius $r$ is $(x-x_m)^2+(y-y_m)^2=r^2$.

Comment: You just did. You added two true equations to get a thrid true equation.

Comment: did you mean the missing + sign?

Comment: Don't delete a question after getting an answer. That gives a very bad aftertaste. As if you were trying to hide the fact that you asked this question. Also, you deprive the answerer a chance to get appreciation in terms of upvotes. Having most of your questions deleted also leads to a question ban, and your use of the site will be severely limited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equation of a circle with center $(x_m,y_m)$ and radius $r$ is given by
$$
(x-x_m)^2+(y-y_m)^2=r^2\tag{1}
$$
The  derivative of $(1)$ with respect to $x$ is
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=-\frac{x-x_m}{y-y_m}\tag{2}
$$
where $(2)$ is derived by implicit differentiation of $(1)$ with respect to $x$. Hence, the gradient of the tangent line at $(x_0,y_0)$ is
$$
m=-\frac{x_0-x_m}{y_0-y_m}
$$
The equation of the tangent line at $(x_0,y_0)$ is then
$$
y-y_0=-\frac{x_0-x_m}{y_0-y_m}(x-x_0)\Longleftrightarrow
(x_0-x_m)(x-x_0)+(y_0-y_m)(y-y_0)=0\tag{3}
$$
The point $(x_0,y_0)$ lies on the circle so it should satisfy $(1)$.
$$
(x_0-x_m)^2+(y_0-y_m)^2=r^2\tag{4}
$$
Add $r^2$ to both sides of $(3)$ to get
$$
(x_0-x_m)(x-x_0)+(y_0-y_m)(y-y_0)+r^2=r^2\tag{5}
$$
Using $(4)$, we can rewrite $(5)$ as
$$
\begin{align}
&
\left((x_0-x_m)(x-x_0)+(x_0-x_m)^2\right)+\left(
(y_0-y_m)(y-y_0)+(y_0-y_m)^2\right)=r^2\\
\Longleftrightarrow&
(x_0-x_m)(x-x_0+x_0-x_m)+(y_0-y_m)(y-y_0+y_0-y_m)=r^2\\
\Longleftrightarrow&
(x_0-x_m)(x-x_m)+(y_0-y_m)(y-y_m)=r^2
\end{align}
$$
as required.

Comment: its all clear now, thanks a lot!!